# bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: ec2.Image()

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, pymongo

When I try to insert the following document:

```
 aws_data = {u'ami_launch_index': 0,
             u'image': ec2.Image(id='xxx')
            }
```

I get the following error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: ec2.Image(id='xxx')
```

MongoDB is not able to encode `ec2.Image(id='ami-xxx')`

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the image id directly to MongoDB. I would have advised serialization but it's pointless. With the image id, you can always perform other ec2 API operations.

```
aws_data = {
    'ami_launch_index': 0,
    'image': 'xxx'
}
```

You can't insert just about any objects into a collection. Supported data types include:

- int
- long
- float
- None
- dict
- list
- tuple
- str
- bool
- datetime
- Uuid
- Mapping
- Byte
- ObjectId
- Regex
- Code
- Timestamp
- DBRef
- RawBSONDocument
- MinKey
- MaxKey
- unicode

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.0/bson/_cbsonmodule.c#L693